# Transaction confirmed but wallet is on 0ETH and nothing happens

Tags: mist

I'm using Bitcoin Core for like 2 years now and I'm used that when a transaction is confirmed on the blockchain it appears in my wallet but this is not the case with my newly created ETH wallet.

Here is a link to the transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbf77f2a4311d904540607850b3e621fe872cdbea4f91c45705b49ab0e38c25ab

Screenshot of the wallet: 
http://take.ms/WJ1Bb

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see in the screen shot of the wallet is that 0 blocks have been downloaded and the block number of the transaction showing up in etherscan is 4829857 . So you will have to first sync your wallet with the Ethereum blockchain, then only you will be able to see the amount in your wallet acoount in the Dapp (Ethereum Wallet)

Comment: I was downloading blocks for the whole night, it did show the numbers you've mentioned before going into the state on the screenshot. EDIT: From time to time it downloads blocks again: http://take.ms/xh46S

Comment: Check if you are connected to the right network

Comment: It says that I'm on the "Main Network", is that correct?

Comment: You can do a geth attach and then check for the latest block Number by typing eth.blockNumber or status of sync by using eth.syncing. This will make it clear if your wallet has been synced or not

Comment: Yes that's correct, but the blockNumber should also show up in the wallet

Comment: Look at https://etherscan.io/address/0xda43a2d8036f431dab6a57c55ba45855ea678fd9 . The amount has been transferred and is in the second account but not showing up in the wallet as it is not synced

Comment: I have followed your advice and downloaded GETH, now when both running it looks like MIST is redownloading all the 4m+ blocks now. Interesting why my current 44GB of blocks don't work... Will update you when download is finished, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71081/discussion-between-ricardo-and-webdev).

Comment: UPDATE: Nothing works :(

Comment: I uploaded a screen shot on the chat.Please check